# Do something when Toggle state changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI and want to do something when toggle state changes but I cannot find a solution for this.

How can I call a function or do whatever when toggle state changes ?

```
@State var condition = false

Toggle(isOn: $condition) {
    Text("Toggle text here")
}
```

Comment: Normally you wouldn't _need_ to call a function as a result of an event. Think of your view as a _function of state_. When `condition` changes, the `body` would be re-evaluated and the value would be reflected. You could easily observe this by including (a printable form of) `condition` in your `Text` view...

Comment: @Alladinian what if you want to trigger some additional logic as a result of flipping a switch, but not change anything in the view hierarchy? Switches may not only control appearance of other views, but might ie. represent some user preferences that we might want to save and then read in other parts of the app.

Comment: @raven_raven My first thought would be that instead of a `@State` it could be a `@Published` property of an `ObservableObject`. Then you could use any of the `Combine` operators to do whatever you want as a reaction to the value change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something whenever the toggle state change, you may use didSet.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var condition = false{
        didSet{
            print("condition changed to \(condition)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

       let bind = Binding<Bool>(
          get:{self.condition},
          set:{self.condition = $0}
        )

        return Toggle(isOn: bind){
            Text("Toggle text here")
        }
    }
}
```

When we say `@State var condition = true`, it's type is `State<Bool>` and not `Bool`.
         when we use binding in  toggle (`$condition` in this case), toggle directly changes the stored value. Meaning it never changes the @State, so didSet will never be triggered.

So here we create and assign to `let bind` an instance of `Binding<Value>` struct, and use that Binding struct directly in toggle. Than when we set `self.condition = $0`, it will trigger didSet.

Comment: We don't need to declare the bind value. $condition does the job

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.onChange` modifier like in the first example below.

However, keep in mind that **in most cases we don't need it.**

- In case of a view setting, you bind to a **@State** bool value, then you use this bool to modify the view hierarchy, as in the first example.
- In case of a change in your model, you bind the toggle to a **@Published** value in your model or model controller. In this case, the model or model controller receive the change from the switch, do whatever is requested, and the view is rerendered. It must have an **@ObservedObject** reference to your model.

I show how to use the `.onChange` modifier in the first example. It simply logs the state.

Remember there should be as few logic as possible in SwiftUI views.
By the way that was already true far before the invention of SwiftUI ;)

**Example 1 - @State value. ( Local UI settings )**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ToggleDetailView: View {
    @State var isDetailVisible: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Display Detail", isOn: $isDetailVisible)
                .onChange(of: self.isDetailVisible, perform: { value in
                    print("Value has changed : \(value)")
                })
            if isDetailVisible {
                Text("Detail is visible!")
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .top)
    }
}

struct ToggleDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToggleDetailView()
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - @ObservedObject value. ( Action on model )**

```swift
import SwiftUI

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSolid: Bool = false
    
    var string: String {
        isSolid ? "This is solid" : "This is fragile"
    }
}

struct ToggleModelView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Solid Model", isOn: $model.isSolid)
            Text(model.string)
        }
        .padding(10)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .top)
    }
}

struct ToggleModelView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToggleModelView(model: MyModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var condition = false


    var body: some View {

        if condition {

           callMe()
        }
        else {

            print("off")
        }
          return Toggle(isOn: $condition) {
              Text("Toggle text here")
          }

    }

    func callMe() {


    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Hi @Sh_Khan, SwiftUI calls body more than once, your solution might work but it's a kind of hack what if callMe function does heavy calculations or makes network request.
2. question regarding your answer
Does SwiftUI call body property every time you change Toggle state ?

Comment: it's called only once for every state change

Answer (score 0):

Karen please check

```
@State var isChecked: Bool = true
@State var index: Int = 0
Toggle(isOn: self.$isChecked) {
    Text("This is a Switch")
    if (self.isChecked) {
        Text("\(self.toggleAction(state: "Checked", index: index))")
    } else {
        CustomAlertView()
        Text("\(self.toggleAction(state: "Unchecked", index: index))")
    }
}
```

Add function like this

```
func toggleAction(state: String, index: Int) -> String {
print("The switch no. \(index) is \(state)")
return ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not work. SwiftUI doesn't call label block once you change toggle state

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use:

```
Toggle(isOn: $condition, label: {
                Text("Power: \(condition ? "On" : "Off")")
            })
    .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
    .frame(width: 225, height: 50, alignment: .center)
```